# Rails - Failing to pass parameters from New to Create in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

This is an excerpt from a view -

```
  <%= @user.id %> is the user id
  <%= @book.id %> is the book id

  <div class="field">
     <%= f.select :contribtype, options_for_select(Contribution::CONTRIB_TYPES) %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I have passed the parameters for the user and the book from previous views, such that I have

```
http://localhost:3000/contributions/new?book_id=1&user_id=5
```

as the URL for the form. The correct user_id and book_id are showing up on the page.

I have the following in the controller -

```
  def new
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
    @book = Book.find_by_id(params[:book_id])
    @contribution = Contribution.new(params[book_id: @book.id, user_id: @user.id])
  end

  def create
    @contribution = Contribution.new(contribution_params)
....
```

... but the user_id and book_id are not being captured in the object when it is created. I don't get any error, the data is simply not being set in the new object. Should I by passing parameters in the create action differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use hidden fields as a quick fix:

```
@contribution = Contribution.new
```

in html:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: @user.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :book_id, value: @book.id %>
```

be sure to permit those fields in your `contribution_params`

Comment: I can't accept the answer for another seven minutes, but this has solved it for me. Do I infer from this that even if you have defined variables in the controller, the create action will only use params captured in fields on the submitted forms?

Comment: yes because your instance variable doesnt persist between requests, http its stateless (unless you use cookies/session)

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks very much for clearing that up for me :)

Comment: my pleasure, great to help